# Unhandled Exception: type '_File' is not a subtype of type 'File' error in flutter

Tags: flutter, assets, flutter-image

I'm making a feature to let user choose and upload their images on my platform. Here is the code of the choosing part. However, I got the error like the title because the running type of chosen Image is `'_File'` instead of `File`. The function `MediaPicker.pickMediaFromLocal` is also used in other places but it works properly and return File instead of _File. I have searched, read the source code, and tried to cast it as type `File` but it didn't work. Can anyone help me with this.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check your library imports and make sure there is no other file imports

Comment: What is `AssetEntity`?  What package does `MediaPicker` come from?  Most likely you have `AssetEntity.file` does not return a `dart:io` `File` object, which is expected by `FileImage`.  Also, don't post code as images.

Comment: I have checked my library before. I'm currently using File from 'dart:io', but there is another library ('package:file/file.dart';) that makes me confused about which one is correct.

Comment: `package:file` provides an abstraction layer to make testing easier. Its `File` class derives from `dart:io`'s `File` class and therefore can be used where a `dart:io` `File` is expected.  If you use both, I recommend using `import 'dart:io' as io;` and using an `io.` prefix so that you can easily distinguish between them.

Comment: thanks for the advice, but it still returns a _File type instead of File

Comment: You still haven't answered the questions. My advice wasn't supposed to change the runtime type; `_File` is just some implementation class for some other `File` class, but it's hard to say exactly what `File` class it is without more information.